# Use django variable (array of elements from sqlite3 database) inside javascript embedded code

Tags: javascript, python, django, sqlite, highcharts

Based on this Highcharts example (javascript code included in a HTML): http://jsfiddle.net/f4Ef7/

I have a template where I want to embed that JavaScript code without having to include any static. Anything not related with JS is being processed by the browser. Currently my views.py looks like:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from tfgplot.models import estado_foneras
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

from tfgplot.models import estado_foneras

def index(request):
    clave = estado_foneras.objects.order_by('clave')
    template = loader.get_template('tfgplot/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'clave': clave,
    })
    return render(request, 'tfgplot/index.html', context)
```

If I use the following code, it paints perfectly and I get what I expect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 1em">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      {% autoescape off %}
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#container').highcharts({
              xAxis: {
                  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
              },
              series: [{
                  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
              }]
          });
      });
      {% endautoescape %}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm also able to write a list in the html of the values I would like to use in the JS. So, I can show the data in the .html with `<ul><li>` tags using `{{ classK.attr1 }}` inside a loop that go through all the records.

Now, the thing is that I need to paint values that are stored in a sqlite3 database. There is a **data** value for each **category** (ie one Y axis value for each X value in the graphic). And those 2 values are on each row of the table. I have tried many things like:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#container').highcharts({
          xAxis: {
              categories: {{ classK.attr1 }}
          },
          series: [{
              data: {{ classK.attr2 }}
          }]
      });
  });
```

Any suggestions so I can use all those database values as a kind of array for both X and Y axis?

Comment: how your {{ classK.attr1 }} and {{ classK.attr2 }} looks like? D you return it as javascript arrays or string?

Comment: My models.py looks like:  
    # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-  
    from django.db import models  
    class classK(models.Model):  
        attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=6)  
        attr2 = models.SmallIntegerField()

Comment: What Sebastian (and me) want to know is generated output in HTML page - could you paste this? Not your model, or other python code.

Answer (score 1):

The only variable you send to your template is called 'clave', yet you try to use a variable called 'classK'.  Perhaps you are not sending the variables to your template you think you are?

Comment: I'm able to access to all the fields from the model classK (I have like 9 and I can read them all at the index.html). I can use clave (= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)) as well as the other fields.